# Reducing upper volume level

Tags: volume-control

My 3 year old son is making his first steps with our Android tablet (Nexus 7). He hasn't mastered the correct usage of the volume slider so he pulls the volume to the max whenever he is using it. Is there any way to configure the maximum volume setting?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to limit the maximum volume.

This has been asked on [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1811739) and there was only the one response since the beginning of August.

Answer (score -2):

Viperaudio can lower max gain and output pevels.

Comment: Welcome to [android.se]! Could you mention the download link to make this answer more complete? And also if possible, write the step to lower max gain & output levels.